# preg_match and remove multiple characters in string?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

Hi I'm using php to program my site and I've been reading loads about preg_match and trying lots of examples. What I'm trying to do is something like below...

```
 if(preg_match('These characters'), $myVariable, matches)){

      Find and remove found characters from $myVariable;

 }
```

I'm pretty sure this is obvious to php experts but it's had me stuck after hours of trying and reading.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `preg_replace` or `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: This question is missing a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to check for a match before doing a replace. It's like if you were to do:

```
str_replace("A","B","ZZZZZZZ");
```

It just won't replace anything. Same goes for `preg_replace`: If there is no match, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you should be using [`preg_replace.`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) If you wanted to remove all y's and o's for example you would do this:

```
$string = 'hey you guys!';
$ans = preg_replace('/[yo]/','',$string);
print_r($ans); //outputs 'he u gus!'
```

Whatever characters you want to remove, just put them between the brackets `[...]`